# AddClass in jQuery on runttime and select the new class

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, onclick, addclass

I'd like to add a class to a div tag in runtime (after clicking the tag) and select the div tag by the new class name afterwards.

Here is my code:

HTML

```html
<div class="black" id="" style="">
  black
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.black{
  color:black;
}

.green{
  color:green;
}
```

jQuery should remove class "black" and add class "green". After clicking on the div tag the color of the font changes into green and a p tag appears - therefore, the new class has been added.jQuery

```js
$(".black").on("click",function(){
  $(this).removeClass("black");
  $(this).addClass("green");
  $(this).append("<p>Green</p>");
});

$(".green").on("click",function(){
  alert("green");
});
```

Now the second jQuery function which looks for the new added class green should trigger while clicking on the div tag but this doesn't happen. 
Instead of showing the alert of function 2 a new p tag has been added (following function 1).

Does anybody have an idea what to change?

Thank you

FDue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the second doesn't fire, is because when you set up the event handler, there are no elements with class `green`. To fix this change your second handler to this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".green", function(){
    alert("green");
});
```

This adds the handler to the body, but only fires it when the event target has class `green`, which is effectively what you want.